# A function to make a triangle out of sticks

Tags: combinatorics

There are $n$ identical sticks.

There are triangles that can be made out of these sticks by lining them up.

[image]

For this example, if $n=9$, the number of triangles are 3.

Is it possible to make a function that results the number of triangles?

e.g.)   $f(9)=3$

Comment: What are the possible values for the longest side?

Comment: @saulspatz There aren't any regulations if the triangle exists.

Comment: What does that mean?  I'm not asking about conditions of the problem, I'm suggesting the first step in solving it.

Comment: Triangles are equivalent if the side lengths are the same, up to reflection and rotation?

Comment: @BrianTung yes, an example by the OP has been included

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let the longest side be $s$ and the second-longest side be $t$.  $s$ must be at least $\frac n3$, so $s\geq \left\lceil\frac n3\right\rceil$.  Also we must have $2s<n$ so that $s\leq\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor$.  Now we must have $t\geq \frac{n-s}{2}$, so that $t\geq\left\lceil\frac{n-s}2\right\rceil$ and of course, $t\leq s$.  This gives $$f(n)=\sum_{s=\left\lceil\frac n3\right\rceil}
^{\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor}
\sum_{t=\left\lceil\frac{n-s}2\right\rceil}^s1$$

Computing a few values, and searching for them in OEIS leads to [A005044](http://oeis.org/A005044) where you'll find explicit formulas and other interesting stuff.